# Jquery colorbox can't push stickyfooter

Tags: jquery, css

I have a site use `jquery colorbox`.

However my colorbox `div's height` is higher than windows size.

The colorbox `z-index` is on top. Therefor it can't push the my `css sticky footer`.

Is any way to solve this problem? or is that possible to remove footer when user click colorbox and put it back after user close the box.

```
#container{
    min-height:100%; height: 100%; height: auto !important;
    width:1110px; overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer{
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height:50px; width:100%; background:#4D4D4D;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to a `z-index` in the code you posted. Also, is the `#container` supposed to be the colorbox? Are these both `div` for these two elements? You will probably still want to add more information to this question. And a http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating the issue would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [colorbox documentation](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) you can use `cbox_load` and `cbox_closed` events.

```
$(document).bind('cbox_load', function() { 
   $('#footer').hide(); 
});

$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() { 
   $('#footer').show(); 
});
```

Or you can use `onLoad`, `onClosed` callbacks.